# Ошибка при установке numpy ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, pip

```
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy

creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/core

creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/core/src

creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/core/src/npymath

compile options: '-Inumpy/core/include -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/core/include/numpy -Inumpy/core/src/private -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -I/usr/include/python2.7 -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/core/src/private -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/core/src/private -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/core/src/private -c'

x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: numpy/core/src/npymath/halffloat.c

x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/core/src/npymath/ieee754.c

x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/core/src/npymath/npy_math.c

x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/core/src/npymath/npy_math_complex.c

ar: adding 4 object files to build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libnpymath.a

building 'npysort' library

compiling C sources

C compiler: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC



creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/core/src/npysort

compile options: '-Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/core/src/private -Inumpy/core/include -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/core/include/numpy -Inumpy/core/src/private -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -I/usr/include/python2.7 -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/core/src/private -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/core/src/private -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/core/src/private -c'

x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/core/src/npysort/selection.c

x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1)

Please submit a full bug report,

with preprocessed source if appropriate.

See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.8/README.Bugs> for instructions.

x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1)

Please submit a full bug report,

with preprocessed source if appropriate.

See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.8/README.Bugs> for instructions.

error: Command "x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/core/src/private -Inumpy/core/include -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/core/include/numpy -Inumpy/core/src/private -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -I/usr/include/python2.7 -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/core/src/private -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/core/src/private -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/core/src/private -c build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/core/src/npysort/selection.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/core/src/npysort/selection.o" failed with exit status 4

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /root/env27/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/root/env27/build/numpy/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-5jOEOU-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /root/env27/include/site/python2.7 failed with error code 1 in /root/env27/build/numpy
Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log
(env27)root@lte:~/env27/social_orders# sudo apt-get install python2.7-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python2.7-dev is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libpython-dev libpython3-dev libpython3.4 libpython3.4-dev python3.4-dev
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 111 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Comment: Как устанавливали? Какие конкретно команды выполняли?

Answer (score 1):

Поставьте numpy из системных репозиториев. За это отвечает пакет [python-numpy](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/python-numpy). Для третьего питона пакет называется [python3-numpy](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/python3-numpy) соответственно.

Comment: Можно явно команду привести для полноты: `sudo apt-get install python{,3}-numpy -y`